# Extend $session in another page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm having issue getting session variable in a custom page like a controller.
For example if i create a controller like myController.php and i execute the @dd of data

```
$data = session::all();
dd($data);
```

I get no results.

But if i execute the same code in another page like homeController.php i retrieve everyhing the session have like user id etc. My question is how i can retrieve session variable in another page in laravel like i do in plain php with start_session() ?

Comment: What is `$request`? Is it an instance of `Request`?

Comment: @Hisham i copy pasted the wrong dd i mean this: @dd(session::all());

Comment: fyi, you can [edit] your question and correct anything wrongly pasted there. You mean `Session::all()`? Why use `@` with `dd`?

Comment: @brombeer thx i correctly fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your route calling this controller you are working in, is under the web middleware, otherwise the session won't be shared.

Comment: Thx that's what i was looking for. My custom controller its not under the web middleware. Where is the web middleware in laravel directories?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is. You need to declare on your route



`Route::get('/', 'YourController@method')->middleware('auth'); //or web //or api `

depending on what you use.